# Bridge sampling Monte-carlo method in R studio for variance gamma

Tags: r, montecarlo

I am using trying to use bridge sampling in R studio to simulate paths for the variance gamma process. My code is:

```
sigma = 0.5054
theta = 0.2464 
nu = 0.1184 
mu=1
N=2^(k)
k=5
V_<-rep(NA,252)
V_[0]<-0
G_[N]<-rgamma(1, shape=N*1/nu, scale=nu)
G_<-0
V<-rnorm(theta*G[N],sigma^2*G[N])
for(l in 1:k){
n<-2^(k-l)
for(j in 1:2^i-1){
i<-(2*j-1)*n
d1<-(n)*mu^2/nu
d2<-(n)*mu^2/nu
Y<-rbeta(1,d1,d2)
G_[i]<-G_[i-1]+(G[i+n]-G[i-n])*Y
G[i]
print(G_[i])
Z<-rnorm(0,(G_[i+n]-G_[i])*sigma^2*Y)
V_[i]<-Y*V_[i+n]+(1-Y)*V_[i-n]+Z
print(V_[i])
}
}
ts.plot(V[i])
```

I'm not sure what I've done wrong. The algorithm I am trying to follow is as below in the picture:
[image: Bridge sampling code]

Comment: why do you believe that you did something wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure if my code is right as I'm getting the following error:

Comment: Error in G_[i] <- G_[i - 1] + (G[i + n] - G[i - n]) * Y : 
  replacement has length zero

Comment: @slava-kohut would you be able to help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code, a numerical sequence was simulated. And it can be roughly validated by using `VarianceGamma::vgFit` to estimate the parameters.

Note that the time index starts from `1` due to R syntax. The sqrt of variance was used for the standard deviation in `rnorm`. And I probably shouldn't add the change due to interest rate `vgC` in the end, since it is not included in your algorithm. Please set it as 0 if it doesn't make sense.

Simulation by Brownian bridge:

```
# Brownian-Gamma Bridge Sampling (BGBS) of a VG process
set.seed(1) 
M <- 10
nt <- 2^M + 1 #number of observations
T <- nt - 1 #total time
T_ <- seq(0, T, length.out=nt) #fixed time increments

#random time increments
#T_ = c(0, runif(nt-2), 1)
#T_ = sort(T_) * T

r <- 1 + 0.2 #interest rate
vgC <- (r-1)
sigma <- 0.5054
theta <- 0.2464 
nu <- 0.1184

V_ <- G_ <- rep(NA,nt)
V_[1] <- 0
G_[1] <- 0
G_[nt] <- rgamma(1, shape=T/nu, scale=nu)
V_[nt] <- rnorm(1, theta*G_[nt], sqrt(sigma^2*G_[nt]))

for (k in 1:M)
  {
  n <- 2^(M-k)
  for (j in 1:2^(k-1))
    {
    i <- (2*j-1) * n
    Y <- rbeta(1, (T_[i+1]-T_[i-n+1])/nu, (T_[i+n+1]-T_[i+1])/nu)
    G_[i+1] <- G_[i-n+1] + (G_[i+n+1] - G_[i-n+1]) * Y
    Z <- rnorm(1, sd=sqrt((G_[i+n+1] - G_[i+1]) * sigma^2 * Y))
    V_[i+1] <- Y * V_[i+n+1] + (1-Y) * V_[i-n+1] + Z
    }
  }
V_ <- V_ + vgC*T_ # changes due to interest rate

plot(T_, V_)
```

The results roughly match with the estimation:

```
#Estimated parameters:
library(VarianceGamma)
dV <- V_[2:nt] - V_[1:(nt-1)]
vgFit(dV)
>    vgC   sigma   theta      nu  
> 0.2996  0.5241  0.1663  0.1184

#Real parameters:
c(vgC, sigma, theta, nu)
>    vgC   sigma   theta      nu  
> 0.2000  0.5054  0.2464  0.1184
```

**EDIT**

As you commented, there is another similar algorithm and can be implemented in a similar way.

[image]

Your code could be modified as below:

```
set.seed(1) 
M <- 7
nt <- 2^M + 1
T <- nt - 1
T_ <- seq(0, T, length.out=nt)
sigma=0.008835
theta= -0.003856 
nu=0.263743  
vgc=0.004132

V_ <- G_ <- rep(1,nt)
G_[T+1] <- rgamma(1, shape=T/nu, scale=nu) #
V_[T+1] <- rnorm(1, theta*G_[T+1], sqrt(sigma^2*G_[T+1])) #
V_[1] <- 0
G_[1] <- 0
for (m in 1:M){ #
Y <- rbeta(1,T/(2^m*nu), T/(2^m*nu))
for (j in 1:2^(m-1)){ #
i <- (2*j-1)
G_[i*T/(2^m)+1] = G_[(i-1)*T/(2^m)+1]+(-G_[(i-1)*T/(2^m)+1]+G_[(i+1)*T/(2^m)+1])*Y #
b=G_[T*(i+1)/2^m+1] - G_[T*(i)/2^m+1] #
Z_i <- rnorm(1, sd=b*sigma^2*Y)
#V_[i] <- Y* V_[i+1] + (1-Y)*V_[i-1] + Z_i
V_[i*T/(2^m)+1] <- Y* V_[(i+1)*T/(2^m)+1] + (1-Y)*V_[(i-1)*T/(2^m)+1] + Z_i
 } 
 }
 V_ <- V_ + vgc*T_
 V_
 ts.plot(V_, main="BRIDGE", xlab="Time increment")
```

Comment: once again you have helped me a lot. I have been struggling with this stuff and you have been very kind and helpful to me. I appreciate your help a lot  :)

Comment: Hello Ryan again, I have found another algorithm for bridge sampling which I tried on my own, But I am not convinced that my answers are correct. I have added my code, output and algorithm below and also the output I think it should loom like?

Comment: Note that the time index starts from 1 due to R syntax. Please see my edited answer.

Comment: Once again thank you so much for your help @Ryan SY Kwan :) much appreciated :) it makes sense now :)

Answer (score 0):

Ryan again, I have found another algorithm for bridge sampling which I tried on my own, But I am not convinced that my answers are correct. I have added my code, output and algorithm below and also the output I think it should loom like? I have used a similar format to your code:

```
set.seed(1) 
M <- 7
nt <- 2^M + 1 #number of observations
T <- nt - 1 #total time
T_ <- seq(0, T, length.out=nt) #fixed time increments
sigma=0.008835
theta= -0.003856 
nu=0.263743  
vgc=0.004132  
V_ <- G_ <- rep(1,nt)
G_[T] <- rgamma(1, shape=T/nu, scale=nu)
V_[T] <- rnorm(1, theta*G_[T], sqrt(sigma^2*G_[T]))
V_[1] <- 0
G_[1] <- 0
for (m in 2:M){
Y <- rbeta(1,T/(2^m*nu), T/(2^m*nu))
for (j in 2:2^(m-1)){
i <- (2*j-1)
G_[i*T/(2^m)] = G_[(i-1)*T/(2^m)]+(G_[(i-1)*T/(2^m)]+G_[(i+1)*T/(2^m)])*Y
b=G_[T*(i)/2^m] - G_[T*(i-1)/2^m]
Z_i <- rnorm(1, sd=b*sigma^2*Y)
V_[i] <- Y* V_[i+1] + (1-Y)*V_[i-1] + Z_i
 } 
 }
 V_ <- V_ + vgc*T_ # changes due to interest rate
 V_
 ts.plot(V_, main="BRIDGE", xlab="Time increment")
```

However this is how my plot from my ouput, in figure 1:
[image]

Bu as Variance gamma is a jump process with finite activity, the path should look like this: [image], this is just an image from google for variance gamma paths, the sequential sampling one looks like this and my aim is to compare it to Bridge sampling for simulating paths. But my output looks really different. Please let me know your thoughts. If there is an issue in my code let me know thanks. Here is algortihm for it, much similar to the one above but slightly different: [image]